# Printing iterative variable values on a list+ how to submit these values into a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Weather App</title>

    <!-- external CSS link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Weather App</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <input type="submit" value="Get Tracks" id="submit-btn">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
    High: <span id="hightemp"></span>
    </div>
  <div>
    Low: <span id="lowtemp"></span>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
              <table>
                <tbody id="entries">
                </tbody>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var baseURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getTopTracks&country=United%20States&format=json";

    $.ajax(baseURL, {
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);


        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       var name = data.tracks.track[i].name;
       console.log(name)


      };
    }});

});
;
```

I am trying to accomplish two goals

**1)** I want to be able to print every value of a variable on a page

I am currently able to console log each iterative variable in a loop, but I would like help actually printing on the page.

**2)** The secondary goal is to take each value on the page and submit it into a form.  With each submission I would like the value returned to show up next to the item in the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use a input type="hidden" created dynamically by JavaScript

Comment: _"I want to be able to print every value of a variable on a page"_ Where should values be appended to document ?

Comment: I was thinking to the table, but im open to ideas